# How to avoid flicker when setting videoOrientation on screcorder?

Tags: ios, video, orientation, recording

I'm currently integrating the screcorder library into an iOS project and came across an issue when setting the videoOrientation property on the screcorder. For a short moment of time the preview video seems to flicker.

I understand this is due to screcorder setting the right orientation. Since I don't want orientation to adjust automatically when changing the device orientation I set the orientation on screcorder every time when hitting the record button.

It is not feasible for me to set orientation on viewDidLoad since recording video should only be allowed in landscape orientation.

```
- (IBAction)record:(id)sender
{
    if (!_orientationIsSet) {
        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation) [[UIDevice     currentDevice] orientation];
        switch(interfaceOrientation)
        {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            _recorder.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            _recorder.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            _recorder.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            _recorder.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        };

        _orientationIsSet = YES;
    }

    [_recorder record];
}
```

Thanks for any hints !